# Sidekiq 3.2.6 does not support Ruby 1.9. (RuntimeError)

Tags: ruby, sidekiq, ruby-1.9

I'm trying to get the sidekiq service started, however when I run

```
bundle exec sidekiq
```

I get the following

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-3.2.6/lib/sidekiq.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': Sidekiq 3.2.6 does not support Ruby 1.9. (RuntimeError)
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-3.2.6/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:9:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-3.2.6/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-3.2.6/bin/sidekiq:3:in `require_relative'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-3.2.6/bin/sidekiq:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/bin/sidekiq:19:in `load'
from /usr/local/bin/sidekiq:19:in `<main>'
```

Oddly enough, I have sidekiq running on another Ubuntu box same versions and everything works fine.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: are you sure the other Ubuntu is running *both* the same Sidekiq & Ruby?

Comment: Confirmed both are running... Ruby 2.1.5p273 rev 48405 & Sidekiq 3.2.6

Comment: Hmm ok, well in this case you are running Ruby 1.9, so that's why you're getting the error.

Comment: Just realized my 'oddly enough' sentence wasn't complete... with that said, what I'm finding odd is that the other box with the same versions of sidekiq and ruby installed and running has no problem.

Comment: How did you install ruby? If using RVM, you probably need to change the ruby version before running sidekiq.

Comment: Yes, using RVM. I currently only have one version of ruby installed and set - ruby-2.1.5

Comment: @Jon How did you fix with 1.9 ruby ? I'm finding same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because you need to run the following command:

```
source /home/[username]/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

try that then run the bundle exec sidekiq again.